# MSSQL Full Text Search

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, full-text-search

My FTS works in MSSQL fine , but when I try it from my website in ASP.NET it gives me this error: `Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text Component cannot be loaded`.

My connection to SQL is good, and I can load another things from it.

My code:

```
string B = TextBox1.text;
string commandText = "SELECT Table_id FROM TableName WHERE CONTAINS ( Table_txt , @0)";
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText_, Con);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", B);
Datatable dt = new Datatable();
Con.Open();
dt.Load(Cmd.ExecuteReader());
Con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.

Run query (SSMS)

```
SELECT FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY('MyCatalogName', 'PopulateStatus')
```

This should return 0 if dictionary building process is completed.

Then run

```
SELECT FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY('MyCatalogName', 'UniqueKeyCount')
```

This should return the unique number of words built in your catalog.

Then run

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'SearchItem')
```

This should return values in SSMS.

Step 2

If all steps are successful in Step 1, Ensure you are passing the right table name in place of 'Table_txt' in your query.  Pass * for all columns or within brackets (), pass all search columns separated by coma.

If you are still not getting output give more details.